# Swift 5 Can't get variable string from a function chosen from pickerview to update Label.text

Tags: ios, swift, string, date

Here is where I got the user's birthdate and converted the date to find their age.

```
//Date Picker
@IBOutlet weak var userBdayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userBdayPickerScroll: UIDatePicker!


var userBday = ""
//UI BirthdayScroll
@IBAction func userBdayScrollUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"


    let UserBirthday = dateFormatter.string(from: userBdayPickerScroll.date)
    userBdayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: userBdayPickerScroll.date)
    /// DOB String Entered
    let dob : String = UserBirthday

    /// Format Date
    let myFormatte = DateFormatter()
    myFormatte.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

    /// Convert DOB to new Date
    let finalDate : Date = myFormatte.date(from: dob)!

    /// Todays Date
    let now = Date()
    /// Calender
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    /// Get age Components
    let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: finalDate, to: now)
    print("Age is \(ageComponents.year!)")
    let userAge = String(ageComponents.year!)
    print("User age = \(userAge)")
}
```

I can't seem to use the UserAge out of the `IBAction`:

[image]

to update the user's age to the AgeLabel:

```
    print("Age is \(ageComponents.year!)")
    let userAge = String(ageComponents.year!)
    print("User age = \(userAge)")
}
```

Here is the `ageLabel` I want to update to reflect user's age by using the date they picked using my PickerView but I'm not able to update the label by getting their age by using UserAge:

```
//Results page
//Right Side Label Outlets for Results page
@IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resultView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var genderLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bmiResultsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var drinkingHabits: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var smokingHabits: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var excerciseLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var muscleStrengthLable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var educationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var incomeBracketLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stressLevelsLabel: UILabel!
```

This is my full code if it helps!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var userAge: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    //Login screen information
    @IBOutlet weak var userFirstNametext: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userLastNametxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailtext: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserEmailText2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordtext2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpErrorLabel: UILabel!


    //submit Login Information Password, Email, First and Last name
    @IBAction func createYourAccountButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        //delete after testing everything
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVidaClockDescription", sender: nil)

        //user name, password and email text field
        let userFirstName = userFirstNametext.text
        let userLastName = userLastNametxt.text
        let userEmail = userEmailtext.text
        let userPassword = userPasswordText.text


        //Conditions for password *NEEDS WORK DATABASE
        if userFirstName != nil && userLastName != nil && userEmail != nil && userPassword == userPasswordtext2.text && userPasswordtext2.text != nil {
            print("User first name = \(String(describing: userFirstName))")
            print("User last name = \(String(describing: userLastName))")
            print("User email = \(String(describing: userEmail))")
            print("User password = \(String(describing: userPassword))")

            if userEmail!.contains("@") {
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userEmail!, password: userPassword!) { authResult, error in
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVidaClockDescription", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }




        //Tells everyone they are dumb for not knowing how to enter their information
        if userFirstName != nil && userLastName != nil && userEmail != nil && userPassword != nil {
            self.signUpErrorLabel.text = "Error some of your account information is incorrect. Please fix your information to continue."
            print(userFirstName!)
            print(userLastName!)
            print(userEmail!)
            print(userPassword!)
            print(userPasswordtext2.text!)
        }
    }

    //Height, Country and Weight Labels and Pickers
    @IBOutlet weak var weightCalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightbmiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightScrollMenu: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightScrollMenu: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bmiLabel: UILabel!
    let heightToInches = (12...90).map { String($0) }
    let weightOptions  =  (50...600).map  { String($0) }
    var userWeight = 0
    var userHeight = 0

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 31 {
            return weightOptions.count

        }
        else{
            return heightToInches.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 30 {
            return "\(heightToInches[row])" + " Inches"
        }

        else {
            return "\(weightOptions[row])" + " Lbs"
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView.tag == 30 {
            heightLabel.text = String(heightToInches[row]) + " Inches"
            heightbmiLabel.text = "(Height " + String(heightToInches[row]) + " Inches)²"
            userHeight = Int(Double(heightToInches[row])!)

        }

        if pickerView.tag == 31 {
            weightLabel.text =  String(weightOptions[row]) + " lbs"
            weightCalLabel.text = "Weight " + String(weightOptions[row]) + " lbs"
            userWeight = Int(Double(weightOptions[row])!)
        }

        if userHeight != 0 && userWeight != 0 {
            let userBMI = 703 * userWeight / (userHeight * userHeight)
            print(userBMI)
            if userHeight != 0 && userWeight != 0 {
                let userBMI = 703 * userWeight / (userHeight * userHeight)
                self.bmiLabel.text = ("= BMI \(userBMI) ")
                if userBMI < 18 {
                    self.bmiLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                    self.bmiLabel.text = ("= BMI \(userBMI) ")
                }

                if userBMI > 18 && userBMI < 25 {
                    self.bmiLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
                    self.bmiLabel.text = ("BMI =\(userBMI) ")
                }

                if userBMI >= 25 && userBMI < 30 {
                    self.bmiLabel.textColor = UIColor.brown
                    self.bmiLabel.text = ("= BMI \(userBMI) ")
                }

                if userBMI > 30 {
                    self.bmiLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                    self.bmiLabel.text = ("= BMI \(userBMI) ")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //Date Picker
    @IBOutlet weak var userBdayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userBdayPickerScroll: UIDatePicker!


    var userBday = ""
    //UI BirthdayScroll
    @IBAction func userBdayScrollUpdated(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"


        let UserBirthday = dateFormatter.string(from: userBdayPickerScroll.date)
        userBdayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: userBdayPickerScroll.date)
        /// DOB String Entered
        let dob : String = UserBirthday

        /// Format Date
        let myFormatte = DateFormatter()
        myFormatte.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

        /// Convert DOB to new Date
        let finalDate : Date = myFormatte.date(from: dob)!

        /// Todays Date
        let now = Date()
        /// Calender
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        /// Get age Components
        let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: finalDate, to: now)
        print("Age is \(ageComponents.year!)")
        let userAge = String(ageComponents.year!)
        print("User age = \(userAge)")
    }

    //Survey Question Number
    var questionNumber : Int = 0
    let allQuestions = SurveyQuestionBank()
    var buttonVisibility : Bool = false


    //Survey Questions UILaabels and UIButtons
    @IBOutlet weak var surveyQuestionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var option1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var option2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var option3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var option4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


    func updateUI() {
        option1.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option1Text, for: .normal)
        option2.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option2Text, for: .normal)
        option3.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option3Text, for: .normal)
        option4.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option4Text, for: .normal)

    }

    //Survey Questions buttons
    @IBAction func surveyButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if sender.tag == 1 {

            option1.isSelected = true
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            choiceDescriptionLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber - 1].option1Explanation
            print("Button 1 Pressed")
        }

        if sender.tag == 2 {
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = true
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            choiceDescriptionLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber - 1].option2Explanation
            print("Button 2 Pressed")
        }

        if sender.tag == 3{
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = true
            option4.isSelected = false
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            choiceDescriptionLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber - 1].option3Explanation
            print("Button 3 Pressed")
        }

        if sender.tag == 4 {
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = true
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            choiceDescriptionLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber - 1].option4Explanation
            print("Button 4 Pressed")
        }
        if sender.tag == 10 && questionNumber == 9 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "surveyResultsSegue", sender: nil)
        }

        //reset view to not show segue
        if sender.tag == 10 && questionNumber == 0 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "surveyResultsSegue", sender: nil)
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = 1
        }

            //if options aren't selected then nothing happens in survey question
        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == false && option2.isSelected == false && option3.isSelected == false && option4.isSelected == false {
            print("1a")
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = "Whoops! You haven't selected an answer! Please select an answer to continue."
        }

            //checks to see if option 1 is selcted in view
        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == true && option2.isSelected == false && option3.isSelected == false {
            print("1a")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }

        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == true && option2.isSelected == false && option3.isSelected == false && option4.isSelected == false {
            print("1b")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }

            //checks to see if 2 is selected
        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == false && option2.isSelected == true && option3.isSelected == false {
            print("2a")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }

        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == false && option2.isSelected == true && option3.isSelected == false && option4.isSelected == false {
            print("2b")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }

            //checks to see if 3 is selected
        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == false && option2.isSelected == false && option3.isSelected == true {
            print("3a")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }

        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == false && option2.isSelected == false && option3.isSelected == true && option4.isSelected == false {
            print("3b")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }


            //checks to see if option 4 is selected
        else if sender.tag == 10 && option1.isSelected == false && option2.isSelected == false && option3.isSelected == false && option4.isSelected == true {
            print("4a")
            option1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option3.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            option4.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            nextQuestion()
            checkAnswerVisibility()
            updateUI()
            choiceDescriptionLabel.text = ""
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            option1.isSelected = false
            option2.isSelected = false
            option3.isSelected = false
            option4.isSelected = false
        }

        option1.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
        option2.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
        option3.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
        option4.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
        print(questionNumber)


    }


    func updateAnswerDescription() {
        //Gets survey choice description
        surveyQuestionLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText
    }


    //THis just checks if Option Button are visiable or not.
    func checkAnswerVisibility() {

        //Gets the options text from the Survey Question Bank from swift
        let option1Visibility = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer1Visibility
        let option2Visibility = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer2Visibility
        let option3Visibility = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer3Visibility
        let option4Visibility = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer4Visibility

        option1.isHidden = option1Visibility
        option2.isHidden = option2Visibility
        option3.isHidden = option3Visibility
        option4.isHidden = option4Visibility

    }

    //UPDATE TEXTs from question bank
    func nextQuestion() {
        surveyQuestionLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        surveyQuestionLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        surveyQuestionLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText
        option1.titleLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option1Text
        option2.titleLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option2Text
        option3.titleLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option3Text
        option4.titleLabel!.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].option4Text

    }
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */
    func startOver() {
        print("right before startover")
        questionNumber = 0
        updateUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    class CustomButton: UIButton {

        override var isHighlighted: Bool {
            didSet {
                if (isHighlighted) {
                    super.isHighlighted = false
                    titleLabel?.textColor = .white
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Results page
    //Right Side Label Outlets for Results page
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bmiResultsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var drinkingHabits: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var smokingHabits: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var excerciseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var muscleStrengthLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var educationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var incomeBracketLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stressLevelsLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use UserAge outside of the IBACTION so I can use it to update my Results View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making separate view controllers for each individual view

Then by providing delegates to pass over each variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have already created userAge variable,just store your value inside that variable

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, 
UIPickerViewDataSource{

var userAge: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Use this variable like below, and assign value to it. Now you can use its value outside of Button action method

```
print("Age is \(ageComponents.year!)")
userAge = String(ageComponents.year!)
print("User age = \(userAge)")
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use that variable UserAge but when I try to use the variable to update my ageLabel the variable turns to 0

Comment: Ok, while printing User age in your userBdayScrollUpdated IBAction method, what value  have you get?

Comment: I get the age displayed but I get a Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value when I try to update my ageLabe.text to equal userAge https://www.loom.com/share/d95256377d7244ec8c0e7bcecb669a96

Comment: I noticed that userAge is reset to the initial value of 0 whenever I set my code to perform a segue to a new view controller.... Now I have to figure out how to avoid having my UserAge variable from resetting to 0 after performing my segue